# Laravel: modal confimation on the controller destroy function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a delete button used to delete a record like so

```
{{Form::open(array('method'=>'DELETE', 'route' => array('users.destroy', $user->id)))}}
{{Form::submit('Delete', array('class'=>'btn btn-danger'))}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

The form routes to the controller destroy function which I have like so

```
public function destroy($id)
{                                                          
  User::find($id)->delete();
  return Redirect::route('users.index');
}
```

But I want a confirmation alert to pop up before deleting the record. Is there a way for the controller to open a modal dialog and get the return value? or does the controller open a view that opens a modal that yet again directs to another controller that deletes or a controller that reroutes...so confused by how the controller is supposed to control the logic this way...

I have twitter bootstrap and jquery in my `<head>` section like so

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    |
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can just control the click of the button with ajax, open a modal, and on a delete button within the modal dialog you can finally submit a post request to your controller.

Comment: The easiest way to handle this is to implement the confirmation alert via JS before you submit the form. You can display a simple JS `confirm` dialog or load detailed information produced by the controller via AJAX. Neither option requires a page reload/redirect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing you have to do with your controller, just some JavaScript will do the trick.

Since you are using bootstrap the easiest way would be using [BootstrapDialog](http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/).

```
{{Form::open(array('method'=>'DELETE', 'route' => array('users.destroy', $user->id)))}}
{{Form::submit('Delete', array('class'=>'btn btn-danger'))}}
{{Form::close()}}

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
        url = $(this).parent().attr('action');
        BootstrapDialog.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?', function(result){
            if(result) {
                $.ajax(url);
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

**Note** don't forget to add the following after Bootstrap and jQuery includes.

```
<script src="your link to bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>
```

You can download it from [here](https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog).

[Working Demo](http://codepen.io/MWalid/pen/FjkJB)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. But I can't get it to work. No popup appears and I am having trouble figuring out why. 

To test it, I have added an alert('test'); at the start of the jQuery script which does come up when my page loads and when i click the delete button, but it doesn't seem the rest is working.

Comment: @Phil can you make a JsFiddle to investigate the problem?

Comment: the problem is that the dom element `$('form .btn.btn-danger')` need to have the attibute `href` as like `href="#"`. Because the `preventDefault();` does not take effect here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/philphil/ru1t1nc6/   
Here is the closest fiddle I could make. I had to use the output from my inspect elements to get the html because I don't know how to get it to work with Laravel's code. Also I left my configuration addresses because I didn't know how to set it up for another environment. I hope it is enough to troubleshoot the problem of the dialog not coming up.

Comment: sorry i edited the 'form .btn.btn-danger' because it wasn't working

Comment: sorry the twitter bootstrap css file didn't save on my fiddle link

Comment: @MohammadWalid how to get the url in the form ? `$.ajax(url);`is return the url of current page